# How to print emoji style flag in terminal/shell on OSX with python?

Tags: python, macos, unicode, terminal, emoji

With python I can use

```
print u"\U0001F602"
```

to print the emoji [image]

but I can't print the flag [image] emoji with

```
print u"\U0001F1F2\U0001F1FE"
```

because the flag is default by text style in terminal, how to print a flag emoji icon in terminal?

I tried adding the emoji `variation selector` but also not working for flag.

---

Yes as @Alastair said, it works on `Terminal.app` but not `iTerm2.app`, but set same font with both the apps, result still the same.

Comment: Isn't this just a fonts issue ?

Comment: Works in Terminal 10.11 El Capitan but not in iTerm. Apparently some of the font flags are relatively new: https://esham.io/2015/04/emoji-flags-redux

Comment: [it works on the recent iOS](http://i.stack.imgur.com/U4Gni.png). It should work on the recent OSX too. See [Emoji flags redux](https://esham.io/2015/04/emoji-flags-redux)